# Is my dad hacking my phone?

Tags: iphone

My friend and I both have iphones. My dad has a blackberry. For some reason, my friend and I are getting the same messages from my dad every once in a while always on the same subject. This has happened twice now. My dad has never met my friend before nor does he have her number. Why is this happening?

He tends to be very protective... I'm wondering if he's monitoring my messages and there was a glitch in the system?

For the record, I don't think I have an iCloud account... so it's not as though my friend and I are sharing that or have any relation (therefore no link in Apple ID)

I've researched why this is and can't find anything! Please help!

Comment: "I don't think I have an iCloud account" can You check it to be sure?

Comment: It looks like I have an account... but I've never used it. Should I turn it off?

Comment: If You are not using it (for mail/calendar/contacts synchronization) you should turn it off. If this is **NOT** Your iCloud account You should definitely remove it and create Your own.

Comment: I dont even know how to use it. It is my account but I'm not sure what it's used for. Also... how would this allow my dad access to my friends number if he has a blackberry and she has an Iphone?

Comment: Having someone elses iCloud account would allow them to see your contacts, and potentially download your backup data onto another iPhone, but it certainly has nothing to do with his Blackberry. You are being paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

No your dad isn't hacking your phone...

If your dad was using an iPhone I would suggest that you've accidentally linked yours or your friends iMessage settings to each others phones... I've putt instructions for that further down incase anyone else has this question...

It's possible but unlikely that you've got **Text Message Forwarding** setup, but seems strange that it would be just your dad who this was happening with. You can check in `Settings > Messages > Text Message Forwarding` and verify that if there are any other devices listed they are all yours.

The other possibility very likely possibility is that he does have your friends number and has sent you a **group text** in the past to both of you, and is now using that same group text thinking it's just you...

There is no way for him to have hacked you phone to get your messages, and frankly if he had, there is no reason why it would have accidentally sent a text from his phone to your friends as a clone. I think you are being somewhat paranoid. There is no easy way to run software that would allow this on a normal iPhone, if you did Jailbreak it then perhaps, but you dad would have to be seriously computer literate to even have a clue, and would also have to be okay with breaking the law, as most countries forbid this kind of activity.

I think this is extremely unlikely your dad is monitoring your texts, and you should just approach your dad and let him know that he sent the same text to you as your friend, could he have a look at it because it could be embarrassing in future.

## Linked iMessage

It's very likely that at some point you've logged into your friends iPhone some how or they've logged into yours and left iMessage logged in on one device or another...

- Go to Settings on both iPhones.
- Messages
- Send & Receive

Here check that:

- The Apple ID on both phones is your's not your friends, and that both phones have different Apple IDs.
- The list of 'You can be reached by iMessage at' addresses only displays phone numbers and email addresses that are yours.
- Check that the 'Start new conversations from' list has that iPhone's phone number selected.

Comment: He's never met her before let alone sent her a group message.. The friend and I both checked our phones for what you've suggested and nothing came up. So weird...

Comment: In this case I think it's best you confront your dad and just ask the question without any accusations... My friend got a text message from you at the same time as me the other day, I was wondering what happened?